# How to undelete an answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

I posted a question here yesterday and had some conversations with people who attempted to answer. Someone with a username 'rkhb' answered my question and he gave a correct solution to my problem. However, I accidentally deleted his answer. Is there a way I can redeem it or undelete it? Thank you. I'm just worried because there is also a tendency that he might see it as something bad and opportunistic which is not my intention plus I believe there's also a tendency that I get blocked if I delete an answer or post. Thank you!

Comment: There is no answer under [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094584/determining-letter-grade-for-a-certain-score-using-assembly-language). Also you cannot delete the answer of somebody else (by yourself)

Comment: Do you mean you deleted your question by any chance? Although when it had answer that would also be strange iirc

Comment: You deleted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074694/how-to-sort-signed-numbers-using-assembly-language which had an answer which got removed after you deleted it... It is now undeleted - if it helped you (as comments indicate) you should accept it as a thank you to the OP.

Comment: @PeeHaa A question asker can delete their question if there is only one answer that has a score of zero or less- Judging by the current scores on the question Jon links to, this one fit the case. So not strange, perfectly fine. :)