# Migration rejected

Tags: support

Can somebody explain me, what's going on there:

[How to undelete an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307931/how-to-undelete-an-answer)

Revision history:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33097592/revisions

Why is the migration rejected?

I guess (I can't check it due to the lack of reputation), this is the thread the author meant:

[How to sort signed numbers using assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074694/how-to-sort-signed-numbers-using-assembly-language)

There is another thread gone away which I answered yesterday:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084367/mouse-paint-in-8086-assembly-language

Comment: Maybe the rejected migration was someone attempting to move it back to SO? (Just a wild guess)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Obviously. But the question was, how to undelete a deleted post, which seems to be impossible for the questioner. I think, this belongs to meta.

Comment: It _is_ on meta.

Comment: @Cerbrus: And why can't I comment it **here**?

Comment: _"comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews"_

Comment: The migration is considered rejected because the question has been closed on the target site (i.e. here on Meta).

Comment: As @FrédéricHamidi says - rejected migrations end up err... in a weird state - anyway - the question this is all referring to is now [undeleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074694/how-to-sort-signed-numbers-using-assembly-language) and the rejected migration has been [unlocked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307931/how-to-undelete-an-answer) and the original SO post deleted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the question was migrated to meta it was closed on meta as "unclear" (it has since been reopened).  A migrated question being closed is what triggers a rejected migration.

Comment: Related FR: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299599/dont-treat-closed-questions-on-meta-as-rejected-migrations-from-main